# Scroll lags in posts(IE only)

Tags: html, internet-explorer

When scrolling through an article on a site, and the cursor is on the table, the page starts to slow down when you scroll it

I use Firefox 88,  Chrome 90.0.4430.93, and IE 11. Win 10 pro. It's strange but page lags happen only in IE 11. What it can be? Probably a temporary bug or I missed smth with HTML... Better to see in practice - [this](http://fortstroi.com.ua/stroitelstvo/stati/item/6835-furnitura-dlya-mebeli-kak-vybrat-i-priobresti-kachestvennye-izdeliya) page for example
Or probable it's the problem with widgets? But they are critically necessary.

How it's possible finally?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Only posting links to your site is not useful. As soon as you fix the problem, this question is useless to other people

Comment: I scroll through the example page you give. The results are the same in IE and Chrome. I suggest that you provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue**. So that we can have a test and see how to help.